Is it reasonable for one country to have a majority of a planet's population?
My planet only has about 25 million km2 of non-frozen land. Its population is about 4 billion, of which 2 billion lives in a single country.
The closest real world equivalent I can find is Asia in 1850, when China had about 55% of the whole continent's population. Considering that my continent is comparable to Asia, is it reasonable that a majority of the planet's population could live within a single set of borders? Would such a country be too overwhelming powerful to function for a long period of time, let alone form in the first place?



Stats:
Country
World
Percent




Land Area km2:
5,576,280
26,643,531
20.9%


Population:
2,125,934,037
4,213,041,776
50.5%


GDP:
$56.48 trillion
30.96 trillion
54.8%


Pop. density/km2:
381.2
158.1




The tech level is industrial, somewhere in the range of 1960-1980.

This depends on tech and environment. For example, if there's magic means of communication (or even transportation), a country with even medieval tech can span the whole continent and control local populace by military moved around by magical means. If there are hostile jungle with some serious animals that really like eating humans, filling almost all continent, uniting would be the only way to reliably survive, thus there would be one and only country. Past that, history can turn stuff all ways, yet traditional national issues might cause one big country to remain afloat.

Agree with @Vesper we need the tech level and more info generally.  (What currency/year are the GDP figures in?  An Australian dollar today and a US dollar from 1850 have very different buying power, and those aren't the only countries that use dollars.)  One note is that the poulation density for the world is verging on unsustainably high without extremely high tech/magical abilities to grow food.

@Sam Moon there is no reason why it would could not exist, China as in your example was very stable even with such a high population. Your country would probably need to be very culturally coherent to minimize the possibility of collapse though. And also if the rest of your world is almost uninhabitable or technologically backwards your country could easily form. Though keep in mind that they would indeed be powerful for some time though look at what happened to China in the colonial era, meaning they can still become less powerful than other nations over time.

@Fallenspacerock I must've accidentally deleted the last part of the post. Tech level is industrial/cold war, 1960-1980 equivilant.

@Vesper In this case all that matters with the GDP is the relative weight that my country holds compared to the rest of the world. 2024 USD or 1850 Australian dollars, either way it's the same basic idea.

@Escapeddentalpatient. Tech level is 1960-1980.

There are two similar laws governing choices: Zipf's law (behavioural psychology) and Halstead's (software science) are are facets of a single single empirical law. If the public are given a choice of N options with no obvious advantages to any of them, and they are allowed to see how the polls are gong at all times, then they tend to converge on a voting pattern where the vote are cast in the ratio 1 : 1/2 : 1/3 .. 1/N. This is reflected in things such as the populations of cities within a country, the frequency of use of words, voting in N-party elections, and so on.
If you have three countries, and people are free to migrate then you might expect the populations to be in the ratio 6 : 3 : 2, with just over 50% being in the big country.
It works a bit like this. If your country has more resources, it is seen as a land of opportunity, and people will migrate to it. If it has a large population, then many people may consider migrating away from it, and seek a larger share in a smaller country. If you have equilibrium, then these are the ratios you get. If you impose some external pressure, then you don't.
What determines the number of countries? China is a huge country, but it is internally divided into many regions. There are regions that you may have never heard of that dwarf even the bigger European countries. But they have a very Zipf-Halstead like distribution themselves. Is the USA a country or a union of states? Is Europe trying to turn into a country? I think in all these cases, everyone has tiers of allegiance: I am a citizen of Europe, the UK, England, Hertfordshire, and all the way down to scale where I actually know what is going on.
If you are trying to divide 4 billion people into countries, you are going to have this sort of structure. I suggest you have one conglomeration of states with a population of 2 billion, another lower confederation of states with a population of about 1.2 billion, and a set of unaffiliated states (a third super-state that isn't one, a bit like Europe) with a total population of about 0.8 billion.

Brilliant and fascinating. I wonder if it's held true on this world noticeably, bet it has.

It can be bodged.  If you arrange the countries in order of population size, India and China are tied, then there is a large gap to the next largest (USA). We can argue that these are super-states, which contain actual states. At the smaller end, you can say the UK is one country or 4. We are in effect saying the distribution fits a 1/N curve somewhere in the middle, and the fit gets better if you dick around with what is allowed in. Or what are 'common words', and does that include scientific ones? But it works well enough to be useful.

Formation - historical reasons required
Formation of a big empire is actually possible, look at China undeer Qin. They had several strong and savage enemies and built the Great Wall on one of their borders to serve as a ward and as early intrusion warning feature; in the meantime their main populace was striving, medieval-wise, at least they could develop technologies, and some of them got exported into warring Europe. Forming an empire that spans half a continent might be possible, you can potentially design the world geography so that there is a single large fertile area surrounded by mountains or rough terrain of other types, and you should situate the local history so that one single ruling entity has exerted control over all of it, leaving outskirts for barbarians and less civilized opponents, just to make themselves some external threat to not stop their own progress.
The main problem here would be retaining control over the land, as many European and other empires collapsed with rebellions all over their former land. This would prove to be the hardest challenge, as there is no medieval tech means of forewarning of a major event faster than a homeward pigeon (which is pretty unreliable) or a horse racer (more reliable but requires quite a lot of preparations; see Royal Post or other post's history), locally a week is enough for the rebels to weed off the majority of opposition (or those loyal to capital) and try forming at least a token military resistance, especially if the rebels are led by a landlord which is also responsible for control exertion, but is not enough to form a proper response, especially if the army has to travel pretty far and the local populace is also not too loyal. This was the main cause of large countries to dissipate.
Making a country grow towards less inhabited areas is easier - check Russian Empire's eastward expansion history; while there was initially active resistance from local nations, the superior training and firepower eventualy overcome them. Thus, your geography might include a large region of sparse food but abundant resources of other types, like wood, fur, iron, copper, gold etc, which would initially be ungoverned and inhabited by some survival-oriented tribes, then, once the "main country" would achieve enough tech, would be explored and subdued, with possible distribution of its overpopulated mainland's people in order to be able to harness those resources. See USSR's 1920-1940 industrial expansion programme.
Retaining - easy
Check current state of Europe - why they didn't merge into an effectively single country? Traditions, local and international, that hold data about multiple wars, treasons, alliances and such, forming prejudices towards people living in say Germany when viewed from say France. Also, local elites just are accustomed to be "kings of the anthill", like say Andorra or Liechtenstein, in fact up to bigger countries like France, and don't want to willingly give up the reins of power, even if that would turn up beneficial to all sides. But maintaining a status quo when there is already a single great country is a lot easier - after several generations of general patriotic education people won't just rebel in order to get some power; there might be events where a rebellion would try to take all the power aka overthrow current ruler over all the country's territory, but they won't effectively ruin the country unless there would be an external intervention "right on time" to capture a piece of land to themselves. This can be averted by proper geographic and historical events arrangement, say if there is a half of population on your continent in one country, have the other side to drown in endless wars so that they won't form a single empire, both by introducing natural internal borders to "their" playground and some sociological obstacles that might be eventually overcome but the "traditional" borders would settle in by their 1800s tech level.
